# What is passive gamma ray emission?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, terminology, gamma-rays

I was trying to find the meaning of passive gamma-ray emission through the internet. I haven't found any helpful article except some research paper just denoting the word passive ray emission. They also didn't define the meaning. When I searched for the picture it showed a graph with the number of counts vs energy that didn't dictate any information why it was passive. And what were the criteria for being an active gamma-ray emission? so it would be helpful if someone can explain it.

Comment: Where did you read the term *passive gamma-ray emission*? In what context was it being used? As far as I know it doesn't have a precise scientific meaning so its meaning would be whatever the author wanted it to mean in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6603774/):

> The use of passive gamma-ray and neutron detection and imaging technologies in security-sensitive areas and ports has had more impact than most other techniques in detecting and deterring illicit transportation and trafficking of illegal radioactive materials.

So it is a term used in detectors

> [Passive Gamma-Ray and Neutron Imaging Systems](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6603774/) for National Security and Nuclear Non-Proliferation in Controlled and Uncontrolled Detection Areas: Review of Past and Current Status

From glancing through  the article I conclude that the term "passive radiation" and "active radiation" comes from the filters used for detecting the radiation, which are called "passive" and "active"

> There are generally two types of coded apertures: passive masks and active masks. In the case of passive masks, a highly absorbing material is used to stop and eliminate non-normally directed radiation quanta from reaching the detector.

These masks are used so that the detectors work efficiently to detect ambient radiation.

> Passive physical collimation shows noticeable drawbacks over a considerable range of the energy spectrum, especially at high energies where radiation fields have enough energy to penetrate the opaque pattern of the mask . On the other hand, active coded aperture designs use radiation sensitive materials, such as B- and Gd-doped glass plates for detecting low energy neutrons, as part of the collimation and detection process, which allows the detection of radiation quanta with a wider energy range.

Comment: For me, it's not the gammas that are passive, it's the detection system.
A passive detection system only uses radiation from the source.
Active detection systems use their own source of radiation and detect what comes back: there are detections of this type using neutron activation methods.
I could be wrong .

Comment: @JeanJacques I agree with you,  what I have called "the filters used", if you read the link it is what you say.

Comment: There is no use of the term "passive radiation" in these quote. Possibly the OP missunderstood the source he read.

Comment: @nasu my search gave this https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.11617 , in abstract " Passive Gamma Emission Tomography (PGET) " and this led to the links given in the answer

Comment: It is this weird thing with English that we put all the adjective together with no change in format to show to what they are attached. I read the title as well as the abstract to mean that the passive thing is the tomography. Not the radiation. I suppose you can have "active" tomography where you emit some radiation (x-ray as in CAT-scan or ultrasound as in ultrasound tomography).